# express-useragent result all false?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using Node js I want user agent details for that i am using express-useragent.
In result all keys all false like isMobile: false, isDesktop: false.I am hitting service from laptop. I got result .

```
{ isYaBrowser: false,
  isAuthoritative: true,
  isMobile: false,
  isMobileNative: false,
  isTablet: false,
  isiPad: false,
  isiPod: false,
  isiPhone: false,
  isiPhoneNative: false,
  isAndroid: false,
  isAndroidNative: false,
  isBlackberry: false,
  isOpera: false,
  isIE: false,
  isEdge: false,
  isIECompatibilityMode: false,
  isSafari: false,
  isFirefox: false,
  isWebkit: false,
  isChrome: false,
  isKonqueror: false,
  isOmniWeb: false,
  isSeaMonkey: false,
  isFlock: false,
  isAmaya: false,
  isPhantomJS: false,
  isEpiphany: false,
  isDesktop: false,
  isWindows: false,
  isLinux: false,
  isLinux64: false,
  isMac: false,
  isChromeOS: false,
  isBada: false,
  isSamsung: false,
  isRaspberry: false,
  isBot: false,
  isCurl: false,
  isAndroidTablet: false,
  isWinJs: false,
  isKindleFire: false,
  isSilk: false,
  isCaptive: false,
  isSmartTV: false,
  isUC: false,
  isFacebook: false,
  isAlamoFire: false,
  isElectron: false,
  silkAccelerated: false,
  browser: 'unknown',
  version: 'unknown',
  os: 'unknown',
  platform: 'unknown',
  geoIp: {},
  source: '',
  isWechat: false }
```

Comment: Did you parse HTTP header? https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-useragent#usage-overview

Comment: You need to add your code in the question